# Save an excel/cvs file from mysql using PHP [run via a cron job]

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-excel, fwrite, concrete5

I have some results from a mysql table that I would like to export, I am currently able to click a download link and download an xls but I would like to be able to run this via a cron job and have the weekly results email to me.

I have looked at doing this from Mysql and save it out as a csv directly.

However I am struggling with the SQL, the table format is as follows

```
btFormQuestions (some columns ommitted)
+-------+---------------+----------+-----------+
| msqID | questionSetId | Question | InputType |
|-------+---------------+----------+-----------+
|   1   | 123456        | Name     | field     |
|   2   | 123456        | Telephone| field     |
|   3   | 123456        | Email    | email     |
|   4   | 123456        | Enquiry  | test      |

btFormAnswers
+-----+------+-------+-----------------+
| aID | asID | msqID | answer          |
+-----+------+-------+-----------------+
|  1  |   1  | 1     | Sean            |
|  2  |   1  | 2     | 0800 0          |
|  3  |   1  | 3     | se@te.com       |
|  4  |   1  | 4     | Asking Question |

btFormAnswersSet
+------+---------------+---------------------+
| asID | questionSetId | created             |
+------+---------------+---------------------+
| 1    | 123456        | 2013-04-30 11:07:55 |
```

The sql queries, I am currently using to get the information into PHP and into an array is as follows:

```
//get answers sets
$sql='SELECT * FROM btFormAnswerSet AS aSet '.
'WHERE aSet.questionSetId='.$questionSet.' ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0, 100;
$answerSetsRS=$db->query($sql);


//load answers into a nicer multi-dimensional array
$answerSets=array();
$answerSetIds=array(0);
while( $answer = $answerSetsRS->fetchRow() ){
    //answer set id - question id
    $answerSets[$answer['asID']]=$answer;
    $answerSetIds[]=$answer['asID'];
}       

    //get answers
    $sql='SELECT * FROM btFormAnswers AS a WHERE a.asID IN ('.join(',',$answerSetIds).')';
    $answersRS=$db->query($sql);

    //load answers into a nicer multi-dimensional array 
    while( $answer = $answersRS->fetchRow() ){
        //answer set id - question id
        $answerSets[$answer['asID']]['answers'][$answer['msqID']]=$answer;
    }
 return $answerSets;
```

***I would like to be able to do one of the following***

**A.) Move all of this into one query to be able to get the following sort of result**

```
+---------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| QuestionSetID | Name | Telephone | Email     | Enquiry         |
+---------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+
| 123456        | Sean | 0800 0    | se@te.com | Asking Question |
```

*(I did try this with various joins but could not get them quite right)* 
*If I could get this to work I would not mind saving as a CSV*

**B.) Output the returned array as excel file that can be saved to a location on the server,**

The current code creates a html table from the array

The code is a little long so I am only pasting the top and bottom bits here

```
//fwrite($handle, $excelHead);
//fwrite($handle, $row);
//fflush($handle);
 ob_start();
 header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
 echo "<table>\r\n";
 //Question headers go here
 foreach($answerSets as $answerSetId=>$answerSet){
            $questionNumber=0;
            $numQuestionsToShow=2;
            echo "\t<tr>\r\n";
            echo "\t\t<td>". $dateHelper->getSystemDateTime($answerSet['created'])."</td>\r\n";
            foreach($questions as $questionId=>$question){
                $questionNumber++;
                if ($question['inputType'] == 'checkboxlist'){
                    $options = explode('%%', $question['options']);
                    $subanswers = explode(',', $answerSet['answers'][$questionId]['answer']);
                    for ($i = 1; $i <= count($options); $i++)
                    {
                        echo "\t\t<td align='center'>\r\n";
                        if (in_array(trim($options[$i-1]), $subanswers)) {
                            // echo "\t\t\t".$options[$i-1]."\r\n";
                            echo "x";
                        } else {
                            echo "\t\t\t&nbsp;\r\n";
                        }
                        echo "\t\t</td>\r\n";
                    //fwrite($handle, $node);
                    //fflush($handle);
                    }

                }elseif($question['inputType']=='fileupload'){
                    echo "\t\t<td>\r\n";
                    $fID=intval($answerSet['answers'][$questionId]['answer']);
                    $file=File::getByID($fID);
                    if($fID && $file){
                        $fileVersion=$file->getApprovedVersion();
                        echo "\t\t\t".'<a href="'. $fileVersion->getDownloadURL() .'">'.$fileVersion->getFileName().'</a>'."\r\n";
                    }else{
                        echo "\t\t\t".t('File not found')."\r\n";
                    }
                    echo "\t\t</td>\r\n";
                }else{
                    echo "\t\t<td>\r\n";
                    echo "\t\t\t".$answerSet['answers'][$questionId]['answer'].$answerSet['answers'][$questionId]['answerLong']."\r\n";
                    echo "\t\t</td>\r\n";
                }
                //fwrite($handle, $node);
                //fflush($handle);
            }
            echo "\t</tr>\r\n";
            //fwrite($handle, $row);
            //fflush($handle);
        }
        echo "</table>\r\n";
        //fwrite($handle, $excelFoot);
        //fflush($handle);
        //fclose($handle);
file_put_contents($filePath, ob_get_clean());
```

I can get the file to save to the directory but I am having issues setting it as an Excel file, I have also tried, playing with Fwrite *(instead of the buffer)* with the similar results

can anyone help, or point me in the right location.

Thank you,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this from within concrete5. That way you get all the form-results-related models, plus the various helpers (like email).

For more info about jobs, see http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/system/jobs/ . To run from a cron job, see http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/how-to-run-certain-jobs-via-cron/ .

It looks like you've got the code to generate the answers, and put it into an array, but you might want to look at something like https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/master/web/concrete/core/controllers/blocks/form_statistics.php#L32 . I'm not positive that's exactly what you need, but I do know that the dashboard page builds that answers table for you, so the code clearly exists somewhere.

Finally, to create an excel file, elsewhere c5 uses the "put it into a table and call it .xls" method, which works with excel and open office. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "having issues setting it as Excel", but it sounds like this is your issue at the moment. If *something* is getting saved to the file, then you should post the file contents and you/we can work backwards as to what is causing the issue. It's probably just misformatted HTML or something.

Finally, to send the email, you can use the Mail Helper, but that doesn't currently allow for attachments (there's a pull request in github that does, and that you could use to override the mail helper with). Typically, the "best practice" would be to send it as a link.

Comment: I do also plan to use the mail helper to send that file as an attachment, once I can work out how to save it correctly.

Comment: Thanks James, (ran out of time to edit the previous comment)
I currently have this set as a job within my dashboard, however an issue comes with saving the file as an xls file on the server, not through the browser but instead using the output buffer setting the Content Type as ms-excel does not appear to work. The table created is good html. The file will save as an xls extension but attempting to open it from within Excel gives a file corrupt message. 

The file is put as a table and called xls, but does not appear when using the output buffer and saving the content of that buffer to a file.

Comment: I am actually using alot of the code from the buildAnswerSetsArray() function to currently build up the answers. This returns the array I just wandered if anyone could point out an SQL query that could do this

Comment: content-type is purely an HTTP protocol header and will have no effect on output buffering (per se) or how the file is written to disk. In fact, the whole use of `echo` within a buffer, and then writing that to disk is pretty wacky. You should go back to the `fwrite()`s (I'd just create a single `$file` var and append to that). I guarantee you that if the file is written to disk as text, and has the appropriate table code, then Excel will read it just fine. Open up the file in a text editor and post the text to pastie.org or something.